# How to return value inside subscription

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this following code

```
fun fetchUsersNumber(): Int {

    subscriptions.add(mRepository.getCount()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe {
            count -> view?.updateNumber(count)
        })
}
```

In my mRepository.getCount() I return a Single

```
override fun getCount(): Single<Int> {
    return mDao.getCount()
}
```

my DAO is like :

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users)
fun getCount(): Single<Int>
```

my View is just a method which have an Int parameters.

```
fun updateNumber(count: Int) {
    // display user number
}
```

My problem is :
- I would like to return my count value. How can I do that? Because in my activity I will have something like :

```
textView.text = presenter.fetchUserNumber()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple, you don't have to do anything, your Presenter will do for you. You just have to call your method and check the result, you will have the return that you wanted. And like JakeB said, you have to apply your OnError if it fails.

```
fun fetchUsersNumber(): Int {

    subscriptions.add(mRepository.getCount()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe (
            { count -> view?.updateNumber(count) },
            { // your Error here }
        )
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Presenter will handle the subscription in it's lifecycle methods, and will send the result to `updateNumber()` in the result of the subscribe. Apply `onError` to handle the event that it fails, calling another method in the view to alert the user.

```
fun updateNumber(count: Int) {
    textView.text = count
}
```